# PHP SQL Joomla store table with two columns into array and echo them later

Tags: php, sql, arrays, joomla

So I have a simple table with two columns.  The table is called "mytable" and the columns are "product" and "id".  The table has about 12 entries.

```
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

So I've gotten this far querying successfully but I want to call back the results of each row. That's the part I am stuck on.  I need to store this into an array so I can later make a while loop spitting out each row.  Also I cannot echo it right underneath that code.  This needs to be stored in an array that is then pulled from another page and then I spit out each row.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
        echo '<pre/>'
        print_r($results);//the resulted array is already in this variable you can iterate it later with foreach loop.
```

for looping and printing

```
foreach($results as $key=>$value){
 echo 'Product-->'.$value->product;
 echo 'ID-->'.$value->id;
}
```

check the [Joomla DB query](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) for more details.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use more up to date coding standards for you query, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query->select($db->quoteName('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('mytable'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Then to get the results, create a loop:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo 'ID = ' . $result->id;
    echo 'Product = ' . $result->product;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Also if you really need an array for another method you can do that directly when defining $results.